# Maintain consistent footers in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I would like to know if there is a possibility to maintain all footers of my [Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word) templates at once, since they have to be all the same. It sounds like a very smart way to save some time.

I appreciate hacks too.

In my footer I have the location of where it's saved, who created it, who changed it last and when it's been chanced lastly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of thing can be inserted using fields.

1. Go to the 'Insert' ribbon, click 'Quick Parts' then 'Field...'
2. Some of the properties you mentioned are listed in the left-hand column (FileName [check the 'Add path to filename' box], Author)
3. The other two (LastSavedTime and LastSavedBy) are under the DocProperties menu
4. Simply pick the one you want and click OK. The field is inserted at whatever location is selected in the document.

**[EDIT] To just maintain one footer:**

You could add the footer to your Footer Gallery (Word 2007):

1. Make your footer as you would like it
2. While still editing the footer, use ctrl+A to select the whole text
3. Click on 'Header & Footer Tools' -> 'Footer' -> 'Save selection to footer gallery'
4. Supply a name, gallery, etc. Save the footer to Normal.dotm to have it accessed by all new documents
5. Click OK

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same header and footer for all sections in a document.

1. Move to the first page of the document.
2. Double click on the header.
3. On the ribbon under **Navigation** press **Next** to move to the
   next section.
4. First make sure the cursor is inside the header and press **Link to
   previous** on the ribbon under **Next**. This will use the same
   header from the previous pages.
5. Move to the footer and press **Link to previous** again.
6. Repeat until there no more sections in the document (Next doesn't
   move anywhere).

Comment: nice answer but, what i need is to have like 1 document where there is only the footer and every of my tamplate uses this ones footer so i only have to maintain one.

Comment: Have you tried creating your own template and using that for every document you create?

Comment: I have serval templates (~60). And they all have the same Footer, thats whats common. Do you think it is possible to initialise a footer by VBA? I found that is possible to let VBA run when it's beeing opened from a template.